# Reading out Data using PUT in SAS

Tags: sas, export-to-csv

I usually use PROC EXPORT to read out data from SAS to a csv or .dat file.

I've been given a readout that uses PUT statement but I can't find an example of how to use this that works for me.

What I have at the minute is:

```
DATA TC_LEVEL_JUNE01;
FILE "C:\Users\JUNE01.csv"
    LRECL = 7353;
    PUT
    @5 VAR1 $20.
    @25 VAR2 $20.
    @45 VAR3 2.
;
RUN;
```

But this just changes the data to a 1 row dataset.

Comment: Not sure what "reading out" means, but your data step is not reading IN any data so there is no data to WRITE out.

Comment: There is also `ds2csv()` macro that ships with SAS.  Usually the quickest/easiest way to create a CSV from a dataset.  Just google it for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of just creating an `csv` output file in the operating system, use `DATA _NULL_`.  The data step does not have a `SET` statement, so there are no data rows to process.  Because you have `DATA TC_LEVEL_JUNE01` it will create a one row output data set *and* an output file.  Not sure why `LRECL=7353` when the put statements will create a 46 character line.

This is closer to what you need for your fixed column output (commas might not be needed for downstream processing?):

```
DATA _NULL_;  /* do not create an output data set */
  SET TC_LEVEL_JUNE01;  /* read record from this data set */
  FILE "C:\Users\JUNE01.csv" LRECL = 7353;  /* place output from PUT in this file */

  PUT /* 'Export' three columns of data */
    @5 VAR1 $20.
    @25 VAR2 $20.
    @45 VAR3 2.
  ; 
RUN;
```

For a *real* `PUT` filled `csv` will also want comma delimiting and double quoted character values.

For example:

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  file 'c:\temp\class.csv' dlmstr=',' dsd;
  put name sex age ;
run;
```

From `FILE` helps (my bolds)

> **DSD (delimiter sensitive data)**
>
> specifies that data values that contain embedded delimiters, such as
>   tabs or commas, be enclosed in quotation marks. The DSD option enables you to write data values that contain embedded delimiters to LIST output. This **option is ignored** for other types of output (for example, **formatted**, column, and named). Any double quotation marks that are included in the data value are repeated. When a variable value contains the delimiter and DSD is used in the FILE statement, the **variable value is enclosed in double quotation marks** when the output is generated.